# Bootstrap modal hide is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap modal hide is not working. **Alert comes in else. but my modal is not hidden** Added bootply. My issue is the same one.

```
<button class="button primary" id="buy" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" style= "text-decoration:none;" type="button">Review and confirm</button>

<div class="modal-bootstrap fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-bootstrap-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-bootstrap-content">
      <div class="modal-bootstrap-body">
        -- content ----
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-bootstrap-footer">
     <button type="submit" class="button primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     <button type="submit" class="button primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$("#buy").click(function () {
   var a = 4;
   if (a == 5) {
     alert("if");
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
   }
   else {
    alert("else");
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
   }

});
</script>
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/TW20tNe3vG)

Comment: check console for any errors. If any then post it here.

Comment: you forgot `;` after `alert()`

Comment: .. and your javascript is just amongst the html

Comment: and where is your `<script>` tag ?

Comment: I have corrected alert. In my UI alert is working. The problem is modal is not hidden

Comment: Added bootply. Same issue for me

Comment: I checked your code.
Now you compare a == 5. but a is always 4. you may have to check this why you are doing this comparison.
Also you need you remove the data-target if you want to open modal from javascript :

    <button class="button primary" id="buy" data-toggle="modal" style="text-decoration:none;" type="button">Review and confirm</button>

data-target directly opening the modal.
Check if this is working.

Comment: @Kshitiz - thanks for your answer. It is working. Kindly put this as answer. I ll accept

Comment: ok will to this. Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are using both modal toggling methods: via Javascript and via data attributes. So your click is firing the modal show as your data attributes set, and your Javascript does not affect this trigger.

Just remove the data attributes and go with the Javascript method:

```
<button class="button primary" id="buy" style="text-decoration:none;" type="button">Review and confirm</button>

<div class="modal-bootstrap fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <!-- modal contents -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#buy").click(function () {
    var a = 4;
    if (a == 5) {
        alert("if");
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    } else {
        alert("else");
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have a problem right now that may be due to this. I could not detect it in my local dev environment, but we're getting some reports saying that our modal isn't closing and the fields are wiped. 

Do you have any idea about the circumstances that would cause this conflict? We did have both javascript and a data attribute instructing the modal to close, but it's only a problem on certain people's machines. 

Is it a particular version of, I don't know, bootstrap or jquery combined with a certain version of Chrome what have you?

Comment: @Femtosecond it's difficult to know what's happening without reading your code or at least having precise reproduction conditions, you should ask your own question.

Comment: FYI this answer helped me find my problem, which was in my <div> class I was using class="modal" and NOT class="modal-bootstrap".  I changed to class="modal-bootstrap" and it fixed my issue.

Comment: I figured this was my issue, however still not sure how to restore ability to close the modal when clicking outside of it. Doing it from the blur() event doesn't seem to be doing the trick for me.

Answer (score 60):

I had same problem. Remove `fade` class.

Comment: I think this class makes a time delay on js "hide" command.

Comment: wow that actually worked! thank you, you are a lifesaver

Comment: This answer should be bumped up more. Removing fade instantly resolved the issue.

Comment: The issue is with 'fade' class. But you don't need to remove it. Do as follows
else {
    $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
          $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
}

Comment: Removing fade worked for me. Thanks you!!!

Comment: Thank you! Modal hide() was working on MacOS Safari and Chrome, but not working on iOS Safari and Chrome. Removing `fade` resolved the issue.

Comment: near 2023 and this solves my problem too thanks

Comment: In 2023 now, and using BS4, this worked for me

Comment: 2024, removing the fade class works. But I saw the bug only when the modal window is displayed for a very short time.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem, tried a lot of things but the only solution that worked for me is @Tang Chanrith suggested to remove individually parts of the modal but a little bit improved to place back and the scrollbar. I'll put my answer just if the accepted answer did not work for them. Sorry for my english. Hope I helped.

> @Tang Chanrith
>
> Try this function
>
> ```
> function hideModal() {
>   $("#myModal").removeClass("in");
>   $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
>   $("#myModal").hide();
> }
> ```

**Improved Sollution**

You just have to delete a class from body and css that generated

```
function hideModal() {
  $("#myModal").removeClass("in");
  $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
  $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
  $('body').css('padding-right', '');
  $("#myModal").hide();
}
```

Comment: this prevents it to open again until refreshing the page

Comment: Yep, the modal doesn't re-open after closing, but I found that if you add:
$("#LoadingModal").addClass("in"); 
in the function that shows the modal, it does re-appear :)

Answer (score 20):

For those still having issues (hi Googlers!), if you're using fade, you'll have to use javascript to remove fade class.

Comment: exactly the same issue with me.

Comment: This answer should be bumped up more. Removing fade instantly resolved the issue. There is another comment above with the same answer.

Answer (score 17):

Try this function

```
function hideModal(){
    $("#myModal").removeClass("in");
    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
    $("#myModal").hide();
}
```

Comment: I seem to have created a new problem by using $(",modal-backdrop").remove()... my scrollbar also disappears!  Need to find another solution.

Answer (score 12):

Remove the modal class "fade" will do.

Comment: short answer is better to comment on questions

Answer (score 3):

I have solution this problem.

```
$('#landingpage, body').on('click',function(){
    $( ".action-close" ).trigger( "click" );});
```

Answer (score 2):

try to add return false like this:

```
$("#buy").click(function () { 
  var a = 4;
  if (a == 5) {
    alert("if");
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
  else {
    alert("else");
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: It worked for me but whyis this working? I mean what problem it solves?

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code.
Now you compare a == 5. but a is always 4. you may have to check this why you are doing this comparison.
Also you need you remove the data-target if you want to open modal from javascript :

```
<button class="button primary" id="buy" data-toggle="modal" style="text-decoration:none;" type="button">Review and confirm</button>
```

data-target directly opening the modal. 
Check if this is working.

Answer (score 1):

In the java script code you need to add one line of code

```
$("#savechanges").on("click", function (e) {
        $("#userModal").modal("hide");
        e.stopPropagation(); //This line would take care of it
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this `$('.modal.in').modal('hide')`

Via https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/489

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my mistake was that I was trying to open the modal window a few times. We must test that the modal window is not already open before trying to open it.

```
    if (!($("#MyModal").data('bs.modal') || {})._isShown){ 
        $("#MyModal").modal('show');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide modal dialog box using bootstrap

Method 1: using bootstrap

```
$('.close').click(); 
$("#MyModal .close").click();
$('#myModalAlert').modal('hide');
```

Method 2: using stop-propagation

```
$("a.close").on("click", function(e){
  $("#modal").modal("hide");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Method 3: After shown method invoke

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
})
```

Method 4: Using CSS

```
this.display='block'; //Set block css
this.display='none'; //set none css after close dialog
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `fade` class.
2. Create function to close modal

   ```
   function stopLoading() {
      $("#loadingModal").modal("hide");
   }
   ```
3. Add set timeout when close modal (1000 = 1s)

   ```
   setTimeout(stopLoading, 1000)
   ```

It's working for bootstrap 4 and Admin LTE 3

Answer (score 0):

As I encountered, sometimes you need to remove display style:

```
style="display: block;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried the JavaScript way suggested in the post, unfortunately it only worked half of the time. If I triggered my modal a few times, it bugs out. As a result I created a work around using CSS:

```
/* Hide the back drop*/
.modal-backdrop.show {
    display: none;
}
/* Simulate the backdrop using background color */
.modal-open .modal {
    background-color: rgba(47, 117, 19, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was opening the modal popup when I click on the **link** using data-toggle="modal" attribute which was bound with that link and trying to close it using javascript but I was failed each time, so when I remove the "data-toggle" attribute and "href" from that link and opened it using javascript then it was closing properly using javascript as well.

from the below few lines of code, you can understand easily

`<a href="#CustomerAdvancedModal" data-toggle="modal" class="classShowAdvancedSearch">Advanced Search</a>`

I changed the above link to something link this

```
 <a href="#" class="ebiz-Advanced-Search classShowAdvancedSearch">Advanced Search</a>
```

After that when I try to close it using javascript, then I become successful

`$("#CustomerAdvancedModal").modal('hide');`

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem, where I can't find the correct solution for it.

Later I observed that what is happening when the modal gets closed when it works well.

Three Main properties are,

- `modal-open` class gets removed from `<body>` tag.
- In `<body>` tag change `CSS` .
- `<div>` class of `modal-backdrop` gets removed.

So, When u do these things manually, you will achieve it,  when not works.

The code should be as following in Jquery,

```
      $('body').removeClass('modal-open');        
      $('body').css('padding-right', '');
      $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
      $('#myModal').hide();
```

Hence, try this and get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Before you open a loading modal, make sure that you close all others.
This is the function is use to close the modal:

```
function hideLoadingModal() {
    $('#loadingModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');      
    }); 
}
```

Now if I want to open the modal I call the above function and open a new one after that.
Like this:

```
hideLoadingModal();
$('#loadingModal').modal('show');
```

Hope this helps you.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

One possible reson should be the order of jquery and bootstrap and your script is not in proper sequence. 
Below should be the sequence.

```
1. <script src='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
2. <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
3. your own script:
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#buy").click(function () {
   var a = 4;
   if (a == 5) {
     alert("if");
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
   }
   else {
    alert("else");
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
   }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you closed all nested div inside main modal div

```
<div data-backdrop="static" class="modal fade" id="modal-progress" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">

-----NESTED DIV ------------------

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me. If this is your case, try to imitate click event on the close button (the one which is added dynamically):

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal" area-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            ...
        </div>
    <a href="#close-modal" rel="modal:close" class="close-modal ">Close</a></div>
</div>
```

`$('.close-modal').click()` should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

give an id to close button

```
<button type="submit" id="modalcloseBtn" class="button primary" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
```

and trigger onclick event

```
$('#modalcloseBtn').trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    G.modals = [];
    /**
     * 
     * @param {
     *  modalId: string,
     *  callback: function
     * } options 
     * @returns 
     */
    const openModal = (options) => {
      const {
        modalId = false,
        callback = () => { }
      } = options;
      if (!modalId) return;
    
      const modalNode = document.querySelector(`#${modalId}`);
      modal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalNode);
      modal.show();
    
      const modalObject = {
        modal,
        id: modalId
      };
    
      G.modals.push(modalObject);
    
      callback();
    };
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param {
     *  modalId: string,
     *  callback: function
     * } options 
     * @returns 
     */
    const closeModal = (options) => {
      const {
        modalId = false,
        callback = () => { }
      } = options;
      if (!modalId) return;
    
      const currentModal = G.modals.find(item => item.id === modalId)  || false;
      if(!currentModal) return;
      const { modal } = currentModal;
      const { _element, _backdrop } = modal;
    
      _element.classList.remove('show');
      _backdrop._element.remove();
      G.modals.splice(G.modals.indexOf(currentModal), 1);
    
      callback();
    };
    
    
          openModal({
            modalId: 'your-modal-id',
            callback: () => {
              DoSomethingAfterModalOpened();
            }
          });
    
          closeModal({
            modalId: 'your-modal-id',
            callback: () => {
              DoSomethingAfterModalClosed();
            }
          });
```

Comment: Consider adding supporting information to back up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

if nothing helps (that happens) - make sure that nobody prevents it like below (my case):

```js
$modal.on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  if (shouldNotBeClosed) {
    return e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here for no reason, i'm not using "fade" stuff.
I open modal and close modal only with js, the hide function is working only when called inside a setTimeout.

```
<script>
var modal_show = function(){
    $("#modal_post").modal("show");
};

var modal_hide = function(){
    $("#modal_post").modal("hide");
};

window.addEventListener("message", function(event){ 
   // listening iframe post message
   modal_hide();
});
</script>

<div class="modal" id="modal_post" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="width: 100%;" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 450px; height:600px; background: white; border: none; box-shadow: none;" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"  style="width: 100%; background: white; border: none; box-shadow: none;">
      
      <div class="modal-body" style="width: 100%; background: white; border: none; box-shadow: none; padding: 0;">
        <div>
            <iframe src="https://perdu.com" style="width:450px;height:600px;"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For no reason, modal_hide(); is working inside the console but not in my code.

If i replace the modal_hide(); in the event listener with setTimeout(modal_hide, 200); it's working properly

Answer (score 0):

```
let btnSaveChanges = document.getElementById("btnSaveChanges")

btnSaveChanges.onclick = function () {
    hideModal()
}

function hideModal() {
    // Get the modal element
    var modalElement = document.getElementById('updateModal');

    // Create a Bootstrap modal instance
    var modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(modalElement);

    // Hide the modal
    modal.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those still struggling, you need to call `.hide()` on the same instance of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I didn't want to remove the fade class.
A simple solution I found was to use a setTimeout of 100ms.

```
setTimeout(function () { $("#myModal").modal('hide') }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#summaryModal").removeClass("in");
$(".modal-backdrop").remove();
$("#summaryModal").hide();   

$('body').css('overflow', 'auto');// this line adds back the scrollbar
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements the other answers.