# How to close Bootstrap 3 modal programmatically on AJAX success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a code that what I wanted to do is to close the modal on ajax success. This is my code:

**script**

```
success: function() {
    console.log("delete success");
    $('#deleteContactModal').modal('hide');
    $( "#loadContacts" ).load( "/main/loadContacts" );

}
```

**html**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteContactModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
<!--everything goes here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything just works except when the code `$('#deleteContactModal').modal('hide');` triggers, it just shows a black faded screen like this:

[image]

The modal closes but the black faded color is still present. Am I missing something here? Thank you in advance.

I'm using **bootstrap 3.3**.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any console errors?  I've only seen the screen stay black faded when there are errors.  From what I tell from you code samples, everything looks right.

Comment: @AronBoyette No console errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677765/bootstrap-modal-hide-is-not-working

Comment: Can you please check if you have set "z-index" of any other element in your css ? If yes please comment it try once again..

Comment: Sometimes it happened caused by ordering of HTML placing which intercept with others HTML element

Comment: May you create a jsfiddle for this or share code snippet with question with libraries you are using;

Answer (score 12):

try to add this attribute with your modal div `aria-hidden="true"`

eg:

```
<div aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade" id="deleteContactModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

**Here is my working example**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="copy_course_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="copycourse" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="purchaseLabel">Copy Chapter</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body content here
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveCopiedCourse()">Copy Course</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**and on success doing same.**

```
$("#copy_course_modal").modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 9):

I have the same exact problem and the only way I could find to work is to individually remove the parts of the modal is generating. Just put this function in yous js and make an onclick event at your button in your html or js. Hope I helped.

```
function hideModal(){
  $(".modal").removeClass("in");
  $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
  $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
  $('body').css('padding-right', '');
  $(".modal").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
$(".modal.in").modal("hide");
```

This will hide the currently active modal.

Answer (score 6):

Ran into this issue myself in a similar situation.

It seems to be related to the asynchronous nature of javascript + bootstrap animations.

It's a dirty, dirty hack, but wrapping the call to 'hide' in a timeout made it work for me:

```
setTimeout( function(){$("#myModal").modal('hide')}, 300 );
```

If employing this "solution" to the problem, you may need to adjust the timeout value. Bootstrap animations seem to take around 125 - 200 ms, so 300 provides a nice safety buffer.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#deleteContactModal').modal('hide')
```

Find  this link

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modal-hide

It gives detail https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modal-hide regarding model window

Answer (score 2):

Simple programmatically click close button of dialog.

$("button[data-dismiss=\"modal\"]").click();

This will automatically close dialog.

Answer (score 2):

This issue will solve by hiding individual elements of modal.
Such as :

```
 $("#modal").modal('hide');  
 $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
 $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This is the unique option which worked for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

I tried several of the proposed solutions and the only one that worked for me was:

$(".modal.in").modal('hide');

Some did clear the modal and the backdrop but then it did not redisplay on
subsequent invocations.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "admin/pc-item-insert.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        $("#showinfo").html(data);
        $(".modal").modal("hide");                  
    },
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22982976)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a timing problem. The Fade animation takes time and javascript cant close it. just cancel the fade animation and it works properly!

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="...">
  ...
</div>
```

(Not use class="modal fade", jus class="modal")

Answer (score 0):

None of these options worked for me apart from the one that said don't use modal fade. However I wanted to use modal fade. My code was making an ajax call to save changes, and then on success was doing this:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
doRefresh();
```

The problem was doRefresh was then updating the page under the modal. If I removed the doRefresh, it worked. So what I ended up doing was this:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
setTimeout(doRefresh, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

**To clear the backdrop**

```
$(".modal-backdrop").toggleClass("hide, show");
```

tested in bs4

Answer (score 0):

I define my modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" id="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button id="btnCloseModal" hidden type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <strong>Waiting</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div>
                    Please don't close your tab!
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
                        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <strong>Loading...</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then I create function :

```
  var StopLoadingAnimation = function () {
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("trigger show");
    $("#btnCloseModal").trigger("click");
});
$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("trigger");
    $("#btnCloseModal").trigger("click");
});
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("event");
    $(e.currentTarget).off('shown');
    $(e.currentTarget).off('show');
});
$("#btnCloseModal").trigger("click");
}
```

My idea is after ajax success is will call function StopLoadingAnimation what will trigger event click on element btnCloseModal ( It like you click button btnCloseModal when you closing modal )