# Closing bootstrap modal on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

i've a sign-in href link that toggles the modal and load a page within an iframe.. upon successful login the modal doesn't close. been searching around here and most of the answers are to add in the line

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

tried that but it didn't work. is there any conflict within my code?

**HTML**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width:400px;max-height:400px;width:94%;height:75%;float:right;margin:50px 12px 0 0">
    <div class="modal-content"  style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <span style="color:black;font-weight:900;">Login</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="position:absolute;display:inline-block;width:100%;height:100%;">
        <iframe src="login.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="width:100%;height:90%;"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "post",
  data: val,
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
  if (data.status == "valid") {
      $("input").prop('disabled', true);
      $("#login_btn").prop('value', 'Logging in ...');
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    } 
  else {
      $('#msg').html("<font color=red>" +data.message+ "</font>")
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What does your `data.status` contains? Do you reach `success`? Do you reach `if (data.status == 'valid')` or fall to `else`? `FONT` tag is deprecated: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically close bootstrap modal on ajax success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122756/programmatically-close-bootstrap-modal-on-ajax-success)

Comment: data.status are from my php json data that returns the status and message strings which i don't think that's the issue as the message was returned successfully.
thanks for the highlight i'll be amending the font tag too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and it was driving me crazy.  As a result I came up with a kind of crazy solution.

I added a class to the `template` used to create the popover. Here's the template used as an option to the `popover()` function:

```
template: '<div class="popover popover-width-control add-calendar-event"><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>',
```

The key here is the addition of the class `add-calendar-event`.  Then to get hide the modal I used:

```
$(".add-calendar-event").hide();
```