# can't hide dialog model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was many try for hide dialog when click OK but dialog can not hide

not use **data-dismiss="modal"** because when click OK button then close the model

I want to when textbox empty then dialog not close othrewise close on click OK button.

```js
function btnModelOKClick() {
        if(validation())
        {
          // what write here code for hide dialog
        }
    }
    
function validation(){
  var name = $('#name').val();
  
  if(name == null || name == "")
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          
          <h4 class="modal-title">Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        Name : <input type="text" id="name" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="btnModelOKClick()">OK</button>
        
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me

Comment: is not model is $('#myModel'). **modal** ('hide');

Comment: typo mistake at `.modal('hide')`

Comment: And the modal ID is wrong.  id="myModal"  $('#myModel').model('hide');

Comment: did you get what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in the line `$('#myModel').model('hide');`.

It should be `.modal()` and not `.model()`.
And make sure you use the correct `id="myModal"` in `$('#myModal')` too.

This is a working Demo:

```js
function btnModelOKClick() {
        if(validation())
        {
          $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        }
    }
    
function validation(){
  var name = $('#name').val();
  
  if(name == null || name == "")
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          
          <h4 class="modal-title">Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        Name : <input type="text" id="name" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="btnModelOKClick()">OK</button>
        
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
function hideModal(){
    $("#myModal").removeClass("in");
    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
    $("#myModal").hide();
}
```

Check this StackOverflow discussion [Bootstrap modal hide is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677765/bootstrap-modal-hide-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

It was just a typo error

change `$('#myModel').model('hide');`

by `$('#myModal').modal('hide');`

```js
function btnModelOKClick() {
        if(validation())
        {
          $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        }
    }
    
function validation(){
  var name = $('#name').val();
  
  if(name == null || name == "")
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          
          <h4 class="modal-title">Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        Name : <input type="text" id="name" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="btnModelOKClick()">OK</button>
        
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

          <h4 class="modal-title">Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        Name : <input type="text" id="name" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="modal-ok-button">OK</button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("#modal-ok-button").click(function(){

var name_text = $("#name").val();

if(name_text != null || name_text != ""){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide')
}
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your modal id is wrong, try below corrected one (model should be modal)

```
 $('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: Ah I'm going crazy now there are two downvotes to perfectly fine answer...

Comment: people are looking biased :) and it is funny. Just to remind them as this site is for building good answers and opinion but not to trouble or take revenge