# Modal Bootstrap does not close

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that displays a wait message in another modal after sending a form. However, when trying to close the modal when I get the response from the form, it never closes the modal with the waiting message. The closest I got to getting the expected behavior was with this piece of code that does close the modal but when wanting to show it again it does not open in any way.

modals

```
<div id="addTestModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="row justify-content-center" style="padding-top: 1rem">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5>Add a New Test</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="test_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        <button type="submit" id="btn_submit" name="submit-label" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="alertModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="row justify-content-center" style="padding-top: 1rem">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Wait while loading the test</label>
                            <img src="http://www.wallpaperama.com/post-images/forums/200903/07p-6606-loading-circle-.gif" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script

```
$(function(){
    let modal_test = $("#addTestModal");
    const url_test_form = "{% url 'add_test' %}";
    $("#addTest a").click(function() {
        modal_test.load(url_test_form,function() {
        $(this).modal('show');
        $("#test_form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#alertModal').modal('show');
            let postData = new FormData($("#test_form")[0]);
               $.ajax({
                   method: "POST",
                   processData: false,
                   contentType: false,
                   data: postData,
                   url: "{% url 'add_homework' %}",
                   success: function(data) {
                       $('#alertModal').modal('hide');
                       modal_test.modal('hide');
                   },
                   error: function(data) {
                       $("#alertModal").removeClass("in");
                       $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
                       $("#alertModal").hide()
                   }
                });
              },
            })
         });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

why you are using that?

```
$("#alertModal").removeClass("in");
$(".modal-backdrop").remove();
$("#myModal").hide()
```

When you want to show or close a modal just use this `$('#myModal').modal('hide')` or `$('#myModal').modal('show')` with the right id, don't remove class you will break everything

Comment: It was the only way I found to close the modal alert. But it is not very functional because when you re-send the form, the modal alert does not reopen. Lo tome de esta pregunta [Bootstrap Modal Hide Is Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677765/bootstrap-modal-hide-is-not-working) For some reason that I do not know modal ('hide') it is not working with alertModal. Therefore, ask the question.