# Jquery code does not run inside an async function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong that's super simple, but I can't figure out what.

Goal: I'm showing a loading modal while processing a card payment with stripe. But if the user enters in something incorrect such as no expiration date or something similar, I'd like the loading modal to close and allow the user to fix their problem.

Issue: The loading modal is just staying open indefinitely, when I tell it to hide the modal, it does nothing.

I have a feeling maybe because it's calling it from an async function it doesn't wanna do what it's told? I am a novice to Javascript and JQuery so if it's simple, could you explain why?

[image]

Here is the Pay with card method:

```
// Submit payment
// Calls stripe.confirmCardPayment
// If the card requires authentication Stripe shows a pop-up modal to
// prompt the user to enter authentication details without leaving your page.
var payWithCard = async function (stripe, card, clientSecret) {
    stripe
        .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: card,
                billing_details: {
                    name: billingAddressStuff.strName,
                    address: {
                        line1: billingAddressStuff.strStreet1,
                        line2: billingAddressStuff.strStreet2,
                        postal_code: billingAddressStuff.strZip,
                        state: billingAddressStuff.strStateName,
                    },
                    email: billingAddressStuff.strEmail
                }
            }
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                $("#loadMe").modal("hide");        // This is what is not doing anything when it's called
                // Show error to your customer
                showError(result.error.message);
                return false;
            } else {
                // The payment succeeded! now process the order
                document.getElementById("TheSubmitButton").disabled = true;
                PlaceOrder();
                return true;
            }
        });
};
```

Here is what calls the pay with card:

```
// On submit, pay with card!
        var form = document.getElementById("payment-form");
        form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            // Show loader
            $("#loadMe").modal({
                backdrop: "static", //remove ability to close modal with click
                keyboard: false, //remove option to close with keyboard
                show: true //Display loader!
            });

            // Complete payment when the submit button is clicked
            
            // get billing info                 
            billingAddressStuff.strName = document.getElementById("strBillName").value;
            billingAddressStuff.strCompanyName = document.getElementById("strBillCompanyName").value;
            billingAddressStuff.strStreet1 = document.getElementById("strBillAddress").value;
            billingAddressStuff.strStreet2 = document.getElementById("strBillAddress2").value;
            billingAddressStuff.strCity = document.getElementById("strBillCity").value;
            billingAddressStuff.strStateName = document.getElementById("strBillState").value;
            billingAddressStuff.strZip = document.getElementById("strBillZip").value;
            billingAddressStuff.strPhone = document.getElementById("strBillPhone").value;
            billingAddressStuff.strEmail = document.getElementById("strBillingEmail").value;

            // else, save locally
            document.getElementById("TotalsModel").PI.value = data.clientSecret;

            // check stock and prices before charging the card
            var StockIsGood = false;
            var PriceIsGood = false;
            var AllItemsActive = false;

            StockIsGood = CheckStock();
            PriceIsGood = CheckPrice();
            AllItemsActive = CheckActiveItems();

            // if all good, then continue and process the payment at the given price.
            if (StockIsGood && PriceIsGood && AllItemsActive) {

                payWithCard(stripe, card, data.clientSecret);

            }
            else {
                $("#loadMe").modal("hide");
            }
            
        });
```

This is what I get in the result:
[image]

**Update:
If you wish to see the issue yourself, go to test.shop.vents-us.com use login testing@shop.vents-us.com password: HelloWorld1!
Put whatever in the cart, and make your way to the credit card fields and play.**

Here's the modal HTML:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade center" id="loadMe" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loadMeLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
                        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                    </div>
                    <strong>Loading...</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what you get inside result?

Comment: Why is `payWithCard()` declared `async`? You never use `await` inside it, and the caller doesn't await it.

Comment: `4242 4242 4242 4242` is a valid test card, so you're not getting an error. Why do you expect it to close the modal?

Comment: @Barmar The card number is fine, there is no security code.

Comment: I tried adding the await inside the caller, but no luck. same issue.

Comment: Can you show the html part for your modal?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteMartin I updated the post with the modal. Thanks!

Comment: I have had this problem before. Try removing the fade class from your modal and have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677765/bootstrap-modal-hide-is-not-working

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteMartin That's it! Post that in an answer and I'll mark it as the answer! thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For undetermined reasons, the `fade` css class on the modal html is causing this behavior. Removing the class should fix the issue.

See [Bootstrap modal hide is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677765/bootstrap-modal-hide-is-not-working) for more info.