# Bootstrap Modal Not Hiding in React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

Here's the modal component below.

The console.log happens in the (isPending == "hide") code, but the bsModal.hide() doesn't do anything.

If I comment out the bsModal.show() the modal no longer shows, so I know that part works.

And I have other places in my app that use bsModal.hide(), but it's just not working here for some reason.

Anybody have any ideas?

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export const ProcessingModal = ({ isPending }) => {
    const modalRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        var myModal = modalRef.current;
        var bsModal = new bootstrap.Modal(myModal);

        if (isPending == "show") {
            bsModal.show();
        }
        if (isPending == "hide") {
            console.log("hide", bsModal);
            bsModal.hide();
        }
    }, [isPending]);

    return (
        <div
            className="modal fade"
            tabIndex="-1"
            aria-labelledby="processingModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true"
            data-bs-backdrop="static"
            ref={modalRef}
        >
            <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-body d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center py-5">
                        <span
                            className="spinner-border spinner-border text-primary me-3 spinner-4"
                            role="status"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                        ></span>
                        <h4 className="mb-1">Processing Request...</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class `fade` from the Modal if you want to control it with javascript.

```
<div
    className="modal" // remove fade from here
    tabIndex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="processingModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
    data-bs-backdrop="static"
    ref={modalRef} >
   .....
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677765/bootstrap-modal-hide-is-not-working) , if that did not resolve your issue.